Debian can only connect to connect 2.4 GHz wifi networks
I have my desktop computer running the latest Debian 12 install in dual boot with Windows.
On Windows I can connect to both the 2.4 GHz and the 5 GHz networks, however recently after updates I am unable to connect to the 5 GHz network with Debian. It shows up in the list but when attempting to connect, it just loads for a while and then fails to connect.
I can connect to the 2.4 GHz, however it is slow and unreliable and the 5 GHz works perfectly on Windows. I have searched up the issue in many different ways and I have not found anyone with the same problem with solutions that work. Thank you for your time!
